# How to make it display like that is in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here are two elements:

```
<input type="button" value="Click1"/>
<input type="button" value="Click2"/>
```

I want to monitor the "onclick" events of those. So I tried with this code:

```
function EventUtil(){}

EventUtil.prototype = {
constructor:EventUtil,

addHandler: function (element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {    //DOM2
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {    //IE
        element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
    } else {      //DOM0
        element["on" + type] = handler;
    }
    
}};

var eventUtil = new EventUtil();
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0;i<buttons.length;++i) {
          
   var func = function () {
       alert(this.value);
   };
   eventUtil.addHandler(buttons[i], "click", func);
}
```

In Chrome, I can get the "Click1" and "Click2". But in IE8, it give me "undefined" both. So how to make it display like that is in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the old IE event model (the `attachEvent` function), the `this` keyword inside the callback handler is not the element that bound the event, it’s the `window` object. So the code:

```
var func = function () {
    alert(this.value);
};
```

Will not work in IE, since `this` is the window object here, not the element.

You need to do something like:

```
var func = (function(elem) {
   return function() {
       alert(elem.value);
   };
}(buttons[i]));
```

On a side note - i second the use of a framework like jQuery if you need to go low in IE version support, it makes event handling much much easier (among other things).

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible I recommend you to use a JS-Library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). 
If you include the jQuery-Library in your HTML-File you can achieve your goal simply with:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At this question,I can achieve my goal easier by use JQuery.But it will lose fun of getting the answer.